# Unable to click imageview inside expandablelistview

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am new to stackoverflow and thanks for such a grt website. I am having a problem with `expandablelistview`. I have a `imageview` inside list item but whenever i click on `imageview` nothing happens. I have searched stackoverflow and got suggestion to add

```
android:focusable=false
android:focusableInTouchMode=false
android:clickable=true
```

for `imageview` , with this when i click on `imageview` nothing happens but when i click on list item and then on `imageview` it works i am confused by this behaviour . Please can you tell me why it happens and whats wrong i am doing .

My layout is [here](http://pastebin.com/m7qQ8UZX).

Code for handling click events:

```
                expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, long id) {

            ImageView delete = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.delete);

            TextView text_click = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

            text_click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Recitation.class);
                    i.putExtra("surah_index",
                            uniqueSurahs.get(groupPosition));
                    i.putExtra("ayah", aaa.get(childPosition).getAyah());
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Bookmarks.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove?");
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    List<String> child = listDataChild
                                            .get(listDataHeader
                                                    .get(groupPosition));

                                    System.out.println("Surah:"+uniqueSurahs
                                                            .get(groupPosition));

                                    System.out.println("Ayah:"+aaa.get(childPosition+1)
                                                            .getAyah());

                                    bookmarkHandler
                                            .deleteBookmark(new BookmarkDAO(
                                                    uniqueSurahs
                                                            .get(groupPosition),
                                                            aaa.get(childPosition+1)
                                                            .getAyah()));

                                    //aaa.remove(childPosition);

                                    child.remove(childPosition);
                                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Thanks and Regards
Imran

Comment: Have you set a `clickListener` to the `ImageView`?

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` on your `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: It seems that you're setting your listeners in another listener. I don't know much about `ExpandableListView` but it looks odd, your views won't have listeners until you click on an item.

Comment: yes i have tried android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" but complete list item is higlighted on first click then from second click imageview is clickable .

Comment: yes i am setting clicklistener on the imageview inside click listener of list item because view will not be available outside of click listener

Comment: @ImranIqbal Now that I've read your code more carefully I saw that you are setting the `ImageView`'s click listener only after the `ExpandableListView`'s child is clicked, that's why you are having this behavior. Shouldn't you set the `ImageView`'s click listener when the `ExpandableListView`'s child is shown (when the `ExpandableListView`'s parent items are clicked)?

Comment: @HugoHidekiYamashita Thanks for info . Anyway i have changed the layout from expandablelistview to dynamic layout and now its working fine . Thanks guys .